# Angular 2 показ меню по клику

Tags: angularjs, angular2

В **header.component.html** есть кнопка, по нажатию которой должно открываться меню в **users.component.html**. По нажатию на кнопку добавляется к ней класс. Каким образом можно совершить добавление класса к меню, которое находится в другом компоненте (желательно без jQuery)?

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/3TfIkPLujox0Kl5giFoE?p=preview)

**header.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {GlobalService} from "../../global.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  providers: [GlobalService],
  templateUrl: 'app/_components/header/header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent{

  public activeMobileMenuAdmin = false;
  public activeClass = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, public globalService: GlobalService){

    router.events.subscribe((val) => {

      if (val.url === '/login' || val.url === '/users') {
        this.adminPanelView = false;
      } else {
        this.adminPanelView = true;
      }

      if (val.url === '/users'){
        this.adminMenuView = true;
        this.detectDeviceWidth();
      } else {
        this.adminMenuView = false;
      }

    });

    this.activeClass = globalService.activeClass;

  }

  admMenuShow(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detectDeviceWidth();
  }

  detectDeviceWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
      this.activeMobileMenuAdmin = true;
    } else {
      this.activeMobileMenuAdmin = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="menu-icon show-on-sm" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}" (click)="admMenuShow();" *ngIf="adminMenuView">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

**users.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalService} from "../../global.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'admin',
  providers: [GlobalService],
  templateUrl: 'app/admin/users/users.component.html'
})

export class AdminUsersComponent {
  private activeClass = true;
  constructor(public globalService: GlobalService){
    this.activeClass = globalService.activeClass;
  }
  admMenuShow(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }
}
```

**users.component.html**

```
<div class="menu" id="admin-menu" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}">
<div class="contflex">
  <div class="h1">Test</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active">List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**global.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
  public user: Object = {};
  public hideMenu: boolean = true;
  public activeClass: boolean = false;

  constructor(public _router: Router) {}

  admMenuShow(){
    return this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }

  onAuthError() {
    console.log('Works!');
  }
}
```

Целиком страница имеет такую структуру:

```
<header>
    ...
    <div class="menu-icon show-on-sm" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}" (click)="admMenuShow();" *ngIf="adminMenuView">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    ...
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <admin>
        ...
        <div class="menu" id="admin-menu" [ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}">
            <div class="contflex">
              <div class="h1">Menu</div>
              <ul>
                <li class="active">List 1</li>
                <li>List 2</li>
                <li>List 3</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ...
    </admin>
</main>
```

Comment: как минимум через сервис. Добавь еще разметку где ты их вместе используешь

Comment: @Grundy добавил. Я не знаю как правильно через сервис. Попробовал сделать, но что-то упустил.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы намного проще если бы был plunkr с готовым примером.
В указанном коде нужно убрать `GlobalService` из `providers` компонент и добавить его в общий для них модуль (если отдельного модуля нет то в main). Иначе у вас создается два независимых экземпляра сервиса.
В компонентах переменную `activeClass` и присвоение в конструкторе убрать, в шаблоне вместо `[ngClass]="{'active': activeClass}"` написать `[ngClass]="{'active': globalService.activeClass}`. Либо в сервисе сделать `EventEmitter` и подписываться на него в компонентах.

```
export class GlobalService {
  private _show: boolean = false;
  public onMenuStateChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  toggleMenu() {
    this._show = !this._show;
    this.onMenuStateChanged.emit(this._show);
  }

}
```

-

```
export class AdminUsersComponent {
  private activeClass = true;
  constructor(public globalService: GlobalService){
    this.globalService.onMenuStateChanged.subscribe(
            state => this.activeClass = state
        );
  }
  admMenuShow(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
  }
}
```

идея надеюсь понятна

Comment: Вот ссылка на [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3TfIkPLujox0Kl5giFoE?p=preview) . 
Был вариант через Input , но как я понял, его можно было бы использовать, если бы **header.component** был родителем (но это не точно).

Comment: Вроде работает
https://plnkr.co/edit/ANbjh5crfY9ES8bSAaDl?p=preview